# Export Layout and save as HTML in XIBO CMS

Tags: php, html, export, content-management-system

I am new with Xibo CMS and I have found export functionality for individual layouts that gives me layout.json, layout.xml and mapping.json files.

Is there a way I can export/convert HTML that can run in browser.

Or is there a open source PHP script to export all images, css and JS files?

Comment: When you're have questions about how to use a specific software, you should always start by asking the developers/their forums etc. since SO isn't a support helpdesk for third party applications. It's for when you have specific issues with _your_ code. Also, asking for suggestions/recommendations about off-site resources (like scrips etc) are off-topic here.

Comment: I have already checked Xibo CMS forum but could not found any help regarding this export to HTML functionality. So I have asked in stack overflow which is large community so I believe someone from the world might have done this before and help me out on this.